# Как проверить делится ли число введенное с клавиатуры на его составляющие цифры

Tags: java

Как проверить делится ли число введенное с клавиатуры на его составляющие цифры?

Например, 123 делится ли и на 1 и на 2 и на 3?

Comment: Вы, между прочим, до сих пор не приняли ни один из ответов на прошлый вопрос. И с чем возникла проблема в данном случае?

Comment: Нужен код вашей попытки решить задачу самостоятельно, а также пояснение насчет `делится ли и на 1 и на 2 и на 3`: подразумевается, что нужно для каждой цифры выводить "да/нет", или же единый ответ "да/нет", принимающий значение "да" только если число делится сразу на все свои цифры? И, надо полагать, цифры `0` нужно пропускать?

Comment: Нужен единый ответ "да"если он делится на все и "нет"если число не делится хотя бы на одну@Regent

Comment: Остаются вопросы с нулями и с вашей попыткой решения задачи. Причем вопрос уже весьма близок к закрытию - если вы хотите получить ответ, то стоит поторопиться.

Comment: Спасибо вам@kff

Answer (score 3, accepted):

И с чего это я сегодня такой добрый?..

```
import java.util.*;

class Test {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        // Выводим подсказку пользователю.
        System.out.print("Введите число: ");

        try {
            // Читаем число с консоли.
            final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            final int n = scanner.nextInt();  // Введённое пользователем число.

            // Создаём копию числа.
            int m = n;

            // Цикл, пока не закончились все цифры числа.
            while (m != 0) {
                // Выделяем следующую цифру.
                final int digit = m % 10;
                // Удаляем последнюю цифру из m.
                m /= 10;

                // Если цифра не ноль и исходное число не делится на digit.
                if (digit != 0 && n % digit != 0) {
                    // Выводим сообщение и завершаем работу.
                    System.out.println("Число не делится на все свои цифры.");
                    return;
                }
            }
            // Если попали сюда, то прошли все цифры и на все цифры число делится.
            System.out.println("Число делится на все свои цифры.");
        }
        catch (final InputMismatchException e) {
            // Выводим сообщение, если nextLine сгенерировала исключение.
            System.out.println("Введённая строка не является числом!");
        }
    }
}
```

P.S. Нули в введённом числе игнорируются. Считается, что ноль делится на все свои цифры.